# Find if current user is Admistrator

Tags: go

Is there a way of finding if the current user executing the application is an Administrator?

I looked around http://golang.org/pkg/os/user/ and couldn't find anything about Permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an OS specific question. I assume you are talking about Windows so I looked up: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330

This says that the SID of administrators is: 'S-1-5-32-544'. This means that the user.Gid will be that value if in group Administrators.

Also there seems to be a special System Administrator SID of S-1-5-21domain-500.

Comment: put such os specific code in a `somename_windows.go` file. This way it is only compiled in for when windows is the `GOOS`. Keeps your implementation clean.

Comment: Good call flexy - Always good to keep OS specific stuff apart from the main code.